# Call an action from ajax without a response

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below is the ajax that I am using to call a action in Controller B while being in Controller A. it does send the appropriate params to the action but the view of it does not renders, I suspect its returning the view instead.

Index.cshtml (of Controller A)

```
<script>
    //some code
     if(isAtt){
         var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
         alert("The current date of the calendar is " + moment.format());
         var b = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
         var id = @Session["currentEmpID"].ToString();
         $.ajax({
              url: baseUrl + 'AttendanceLogs/Index?EnrollNumber=' + id + '&StartDate=' + b.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
              data: '',
          });
     }
</script>
```

ControllerB:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Page, int? EnrollNumber, DateTime? StartDate)
{
    if (EnrollNumber != null && StartDate != null)
    {
        ViewBag.singleRec = "singleRec";
        TempData["enrollNum"] = EnrollNumber;
        TempData["StartDate"] = StartDate;
        var empId = db.Emps.Where(x => x.EnrollNumber == EnrollNumber.ToString()).Select(x => x.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
        var attLogs = db.AttLogs.Where(x => x.EmpID == empId && x.Date == StartDate).ToList().ToPagedList(Page ?? 1, 3);
        return View(attLogs);
    }
    else
    {
        // some more code
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making an ajax call, but you do not do anything with the html you return (which should be a partial view, not a view). In the `success` callback, you need to add it to the DOM - e.g. `success: function(response) { $(someElement).html(response); }`

Comment: You mean I have to change the view to `return PartialView(attLogs);`?

Comment: Isnt there anyway I do not get a return and just the view of the action is rendered? called?

Comment: Yes (you do not want the layout etc rendered again)

Comment: but I am calling the ajax from a different view and the other one has a different layout

Comment: why dont u return any flag from AJAX method and use windows.location.href to redirect to your view?? that would be good

Comment: Sorry, you are not making sense. The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **same** page. From your previous comments it now sounds like you want to redirect to the `Index` view of `AttendanceLogsController` - in which case **do not use ajax**

Comment: Pardon me but yes it is a redirect in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not require [`Ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) if the purpose is redirection only;

Instead of:

```
 $.ajax({
              url: baseUrl + 'AttendanceLogs/Index?EnrollNumber=' + id + '&StartDate=' + b.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
              data: '',
          });
```

Try this:

```
window.location.href = baseUrl + "AttendanceLogs/Index?EnrollNumber=" + id + "&StartDate=" + b.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```